# How to check if the context is there rather than isMounted because I'm using Stateless Widget

Tags: flutter, stateless, stateful

I'm using StateLess Widget and I want to check if the context not disposed before showing up the dialog, without using the isMounted method so is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/111488 there is currently no way to do that, but it should be available soon as this [PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/111619) was merged. It is currently in the beta branch.

Edit: as of Flutter 3.7.0 you can use `BuildContext.mounted`. Check https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/release-notes/release-notes-3.7.0